# A word for "an acronym made to remember sequences"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, acronyms

Example: In elementary math, students learn to remember the prioritization sequence:

> Paranthesis, exponents, multiplication, divison, addition, subtraction.

To remember this, all first letters are gathered in an acronym: `PEMDAS`

The term `acronym` just means any pronounceable abbreviation, such as `NASA` or `.COM`, and is not necessarily about abbreviations made for the purpose of remembering a sequence.

**Does a term for "*an acronym created in order to remember a sequence*" exist in English?**

It does exist in my native language, which is why I am looking for an equivalent term in English. In Danish we have the word `huskeord`, literally translating to `remember-word` or `reminder-word`. This term is used for instance in [military contexts](http://feltspaden.dk/forsvaret-indfoerer-nye-huskeord-der-skal-hjaelpe-med-at-huske-huskeord/), where you must remember orders of action or sequences accurately and quickly.

Does `huskeord` have an English translation? I do not know what to search for in dictionaries and have been unable to find anything on the internet, thus I am asking here on this forum.

Answer (score 4):

There is the word **mnemonic** about which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mnemonic) says

> **mnemonic**
>   NOUN
>
> A system such as a pattern of letters, ideas, or associations which assists in remembering something.
>   *the usual mnemonic for star types is O Be A Fine Girl Kiss Me*

It is pronounced with a silent initial **m**. It can be an acronym, such as

> **BODMAS** (Brackets, Orders, Division or Multiplication, Addition or Subtraction)

which is similar to the one in the question. Another, to remember the 10 organ systems of the human body is

> **NICER DRUMS** (Nervous, Integumentary, Circulatory, Endocrine, Respiratory, Digestive, Reproductive, Urinary, Muscular, Skeletal)

Comment: A Mnemonic is also a great way to remember a moderately complex password - creating a sentence where the initials represent the characters/digits (or a reminder of the character/digit - 'A' could be a 4 for instance) "**I W**on't **l**et **A**nyone **S**ee **M**y **P**assword **!** = 1WL45mp!

Answer (score 0):

The term mnemonic is the best fit to describe a remember-word, but in English it can also commonly refer to a song or rhyme.